# Order_by Rails Serializer transformation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, serialization, active-model-serializers

My understanding is that you can only call the AMS when you're using render like this:

`render json: foos, each_serializer: FoosSerializer`

But what if I wanted to do something with the result from the serialized resource after it's been serialized? Is that possible? My issue is that my serializer calls a method on the resource to transform one of the resource's attributes and I need to order by that attribute before passing it to the front end.

When I do the below:

```
ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(
  foos, 
  each_serializer: FoosSerializer
).to_json
```

I get back json, but can I transform it back to something that I can call `order_by` on?

EDIT:

I have this:

```
JSON.parse(ActiveModel::SerializableResource.new(
        foos, 
        each_serializer: FoosSerializer
      ).to_json).sort {|x,y| x[:name] <=> y[:name]}
```

But this seems silly to call `to_json` and `parse` in order to call order between as I still need to do something with the parsed result after ward.

Comment: Is foo a collection?

Comment: @AnkitG yes it's a collection

Answer (score 2):

How about creating another transformer serializer as `FooSortSerializer`

```
class FooSortSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer

  def attributes(_options = {}, _reload = false)
    object.collect do |foo_instance|
       FooSerializer.new(foo_instance).attributes
    end.sort {|x,y| x[:name] <=> y[:name]
  end
end
```

In controller

```
render json: foos, serializer: FooSortSerializer
```

Comment: Sorry I misread your earlier question, foo is not a collection. It's a resource that has an attribute that I want to sort by, such as name. That name attribute is transformed by a serializer so I want to sort after the transformation

Comment: The answer you have provided sorts within the resource rather than by with the resource in regards to each other

Comment: It will first serialize all the resources and thn sort the output. I have added the sort you are doing in my answer. You can also sort the object before serialization IMO

Comment: I'm getting a `NoMethodError (undefined method merge for nil:NilClass):`

Comment: I think the issue is that I'mg etting back an array of objects, but Rails wants an array of AR objects